# Intent to open call in progress

Tags: android, android-intent, call

What's the correct intent to go to the call in progress activity? Like the default lock screen have here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will take you to the current call in progress activity